# How can I use a parent route's layout on the loading screen for a sub route?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

**App Outline**
I am working in Next JS 13, with the app router. My current (simplified) app structure is:

```
app
-(landing)
  - page.js
  - layout.js
-(results)
  - layout.js
  - loading.js
  - results
    - page.js
-components
   - vapourTrails.js
```

From my landing page, I submit a form which then takes me to my results page. This requires an API fetch, so I have a loading.js page to improve the user experience here.
I have also created a background animation (vapourTrails) with anime.js, which loops constantly in the background of my screen. This is currently embedded in the layout for my landing page. It is blurred when on the landing page thanks to a blurring div above it (in z-axis), but when moving to the loading screen, I would like it to **continue seamlessly** while I remove the blurring div.
Once the loading is completed, I would like my results page to show. This page will **not** have the vapourTrails animation.
**Problem**
My animation takes a couple of seconds to come into view. It is currently embedded on the layout for my landing page. I would like to use this same layout for my loading screen for the results route - so that the **animation does not get interrupted**. However, I then need my results page itself to use a different layout - one without the animation. Is it possible for a page's loading screen to use the layout of the previous page?
Of course, any suggestions of other ways of achieving my described functionality are very welcome.

I've tried adding the vapourTrails animation directly into the results>loading.js file, but this causes the animation to restart when moving from landing>page.js to results>loading.js.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent route's layout on the loading screen for a sub route in Next.js.

You can leverage the useRouter hook provided by Next.js and conditionally render the layout based on the current route.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import LandingLayout from '../components/landing/layout';
import ResultsLayout from '../components/results/layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  // Check if the current route is the loading screen for the results page
  const isLoadingResults = router.route === '/results/loading';

  // Render the appropriate layout based on the current route
  const Layout = isLoadingResults ? LandingLayout : ResultsLayout;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm having a little trouble understanding it (probably due to my inexperience), could you please explain what file this code refers to? I.e., would this code be my results>page.js ? Also, I've seen that the useRouter hook requires the component to be set to use client-side rendering. I'm hesitant to apply that to a whole page/layout. Are there any other methods more suitable to Next.js's app router SSR methodology?